# Upload files to a directory on the server and write their path to database

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to upload files to a directory on the server, but write the path to them in the database for the next use I used: HTML:

```
  <form class="form-contact" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><label>Some file 1</label><input type="file" name="file"/></p>
    <p><label>Some file 2</label><input type="file" name="file1"/></p>
    <button class="pushable">
    <span class="shadow"></span>
    <span class="edge"></span>
    <span class="front">
      Submit
    </span>
  </button>
  </form>
```

Python code:

```
class some_to_db(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    file = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    file1 = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
def __repr__(self):
    return '<Article %r>' % self.id

@app.route("/create", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.form['file']
        file1 = request.form['file1']


article = Article(file=file, file1=file1)
f = request.files['file']
f.save(os.path.join(
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename)))
g = request.files['file1']
g.save(os.path.join(
    app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(g.filename)))

try:
    db.session.add(article)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/admin')

except:
    return "ERROR write to DB"
else:
    return render_template('create.html', title="UPLOAD")
```

But when I click "Submit" I get an error while writing the db
[Flask debug][1]

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!!!

Comment: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'file'

Comment: file downloading pass, but path and name to filename not written to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables `file` and `file1` are of type [`FileStorage`](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.FileStorage.html#werkzeug-filestorage) but your `some_to_db` class `file` and `file1` attributes are string fields! You are passing the wrong types in the call `article = Article(file=file, file1=file1)`.

Your `create` should look something like (untested):

```
@app.route("/create", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create():
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.form['file']
        file1 = request.form['file1']

        # get path for file
        file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(file.filename))

        # get path for file1
        file1_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(file1.filename))

        # save the files
        file.save(file_path)
        file1.save(file1_path)

        try:
            # now create the db Article 
            article = Article(file=file_path, file1=file1_path, date=datetime.utcnow())        
            db.session.add(article)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/admin')
        except:
            db.session.rollback()
            return "ERROR write to DB"
        else:
            return render_template('create.html', title="UPLOAD")
```